# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling'

Tags: angular, primeng

I am encountering the error: **"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling'"** as soon as I add import TableModule from primeNG in app.module.ts. Why is this error is thrown? I don't see any module dependency mentioned in the primeNG documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table.

**Error:**

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling' in '/Users/admin/angular/MovieApp/node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown'

        import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
    ...
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,CarouselModule,FieldsetModule,BrowserAnimationsModule,LightboxModule,
        ScrollPanelModule,TableModule
      ],...
```

Comment: did you try to install cdk? ```npm install @angular/cdk --save```

Comment: yes, I did, the compilation error is resolved. I will try to use in the component. Between I am trying to understand how is it dependent to TableModule while in the primeng documentation, it is mentioned as dependency: None.

Comment: which version of angular and primeng are you using?

Comment: "@angular/core": "~7.1.0", "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.0",

Comment: see https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/03e6546ab67d7cd045c45c612aad7ae44b77ae91 primeng uses cdk as devDependencies in version 7.1.0.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Using `npm install @angular/cdk --save` would resolve this.

It needs it because the `p-table` uses the `p-paginator` which uses `p-dropdown`, which this needs the cdk.

You can check it here:

- Table:
  https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/7.1.0/src/app/components/table/table.ts
- Paginator:
  https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/7.1.0/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts
- Dropdown:     https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/7.1.0/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to restart my IDE afterwards before it was picked up, a recompilation and restart of processes wasn't enough (using WebStorm)

Comment: So, installing npm modules that require cdk do not result in cdk being install if it is needed?

Comment: strange, I think prime-ng should at least list @angular/cdk as a peer dependency in its package.json. Or mention in the docs that the CDK needs to be installed. Not so dev-friendly to let everyone run into that error when using the Table module.

Answer (score 2):

Which angular version are you using. Angular 9 was removed `ScrollDispatchModule` in `'@angular/cdk/scrolling'` from last version. you can use it without importing the module . If not you can import the `ScrollingModule` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just un update

When you import the PrimeNg 13.0.3 TableModule in your Angular 13.1.0, is enough to break the compiler because the module is still dependent on @angular/cdk/scrolling.

To solve, you need to install angular/cdk, as already mentioned in the accepted response.

Answer (score 0):

Just install a primeng version that is OK with your cdk, other way around. But changing your cdk version for primeng could mess with other dependencies and packages that you've already installed

Answer (score 0):

Check your "package.json"to confirm if "@angular/cdk" is installed. If its not, install it. If it is, press "CTRL C" to cut out and reserve with "ng serve"

Answer (score -2):

Regarding to the primeNg documentation you need to install CDK package:

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

Also, you can check this page:
https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Comment: @Daniel Piñeiro already mentioned this

Answer (score -3):

ng add @angular/material

> Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Indigo/Pink
>
> ❯ Indigo/Pink        [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]
>  
>    ❯ Deep Purple/Amber  [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=deeppurple-amber ] 
>    ❯ Pink/Blue Grey     [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=pink-bluegrey ]
>    ❯ Purple/Green       [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=purple-green ]
>   
>   Choose Hammer.js (Gesture recognition support) and Angular browser animation service.
>   
> # Set up HammerJS for gesture recognition? (Y/n) = Y
>   
> # ? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? (Y/n) = Y

Comment: This is obviously copied from [here](https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-drag-and-drop-tutorial-with-example/). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24991982).