# Checkboxmodule isn't working. Angular Material

Tags: angular

Added sidebar component with ng generate @angular/material:material-nav. Then, when tried add new MatCheckboxmodule in app.module, here is error. Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error:

Error: ./src/app/sidebar/sidebar.component.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/platform/index' in 'D:\Works C#\ToDo\ToDo\ui\src\app\sidebar'

Where i should to connect this module yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Angular CDK using :

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

This will help resolve the issue :)

Attribution for @DanielPiñeiro in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610314/14945696)